# SQL Server Row Level Security with lookup table

Tags: sql-server

I want to implement SQL Server Row Level Security with lookup table. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) document and was able to get the basic function working.

But I want to use lookup tableas mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlsecurity/row-level-security-performance-and-common-patterns#pattern-2-row-assignments-in-a-lookup-table) but external table as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16#external).

Following is the schema for Data & User (lookup) Table

**RLS_Sellout** ( external table ) : [ `Id`, `Operator`, `Sales`, `ProviderId` ]

**RLS_User** : [ `Id`, `Email`, `ProviderId`, `TableName`, `isAuthorized` ]

When user run a query on Data table, Filter Function should show only data for authorized ProviderId for the user, which is mapped in User table.

I tried to create function `WITH SCHEMABINDING` but it gave me error

```
The option 'SCHEMABINDING' is not supported with external tables.
```

But following function without schemabinding is working so far with email mapping.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_RLS_SellData
         (@ProviderID AS INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
(
    SELECT 1 as Result
    FROM [RLS_Sellout] d
    INNER JOIN [RLS_User] e ON e.ProviderID = d.ProviderID
    WHERE ( d.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND e.[Email] = System_USER )
);
```

I am using Users Authenticated `username` as Email for matching

I want to add **TableName** as a part of of the filter function, where it will check if user is authorized (`isAuthorized`) to access the table (`TableName`) and then perform the filtering.

**Update Jul 28** :
I managed to create function after answer provided by @[Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_RLS_SellData
(
  @ProviderID int,
  @TableName  sysname
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT 1 as Result
      FROM dbo.RLS_Sellout AS d
      INNER JOIN dbo.RLS_User AS e 
      ON e.ProviderID      = d.ProviderID
      WHERE d.ProviderID   = @ProviderID 
        AND e.Email        = SYSTEM_USER
        AND e.TableName    = @TableName
        AND e.IsAuthorized = 1
  );
```

But following policy creation failed

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY RLS_Sellout 
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.FN_RLS_Sellout(ProviderID, TableName)
    ON [dbo].[RLS_Sellout]
    WITH (STATE = ON);
```

with error

```
Invalid column name 'TableName'. Cannot schema bind security policy 'RLS_Sellout'. 'rls.FN_RLS_Sellout' is not schema bound.
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: well, noone says you can't pass a tablename as a second parameter to  your RLS function

Comment: hmm,but what tablename are you gonna process? I thought you were just gonna hardcode 'RLS_Sellout' when you create the policy

Comment: I want to keep it dynamic, but its not possible then I would hardcoad `RLS_Sellout`

Comment: ok, so, you have multiple tables that all contain ProviderID and that you want to use row level security for?

Comment: No, I will be using same script for multiple tables in future. I can hardcode Table name in policy script.

Comment: So if   'SCHEMABINDING' is not supported with external tables and so you can't schema bind the function referencing the table have you tried creating the security policy with `SCHEMABINDING = OFF` rather than the default of `ON`?  [users will need SELECT permissions on these additional tables and functions to query the target table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i suggest following solution.

Create generic RLS function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_RLS_Check
(
  @ProviderID int,
  @TableName  sysname
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT 1 as Result
      FROM dbo.RLS_User AS e 
      WHERE d.ProviderID   = @ProviderID 
        AND e.Email        = SYSTEM_USER
        AND e.TableName    = @TableName
        AND e.IsAuthorized = 1
  );
```

Then each new table script, you can do:

```sql
declare @tablename sysname = 'yourtableName'

EXEC(N'
CREATE SECURITY POLICY ' + @tablename + N'
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.FN_RLS_Check(ProviderID, ''' + @tablename + ''')
    ON [dbo].[' + @tablename + N']
    WITH (STATE = ON)')
```

This way it will be easy to create new RLS checks.